# How to stop Hybris from indexing an itemtype?

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

I am planning to use the Solr provided by Hybris for managing the fields and use it independently via REST services exposed by Solr(UPDATE etc).

I created a new itemtype and created a new Solr core by creating a new SolrIndexedType and mentioning the indexer query and running the same during system update.

Now I want to independently manage this core and the schema.However, my concern is the cronjob will keep on indexing it,and my data coming from web services might not be persisted.

How to prevent the cronjob to index this itemtype or is there a better way for this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify item type explicitly in the solr indexer full or update query (SolrIndexerQuery). You can find that in solr.impex from where cronjob picks query and executes indexing.

```
Select {c.code},{p.code} from {Product as p}, {ComposedType as c} where {c.pk} = {p.itemType} and {c.code} not in ('YourItemType1','ItemType2',...)
```